# Unable to set client connection character set: utf8 in Codeigniter

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

At first, I connect my database and got this problem issue:

> Unable to set client connection character set: utf8
>
> Filename: core/Loader.php
>
> Line Number: 323

[image]

In my loader.php got this line error

```
$CI->$name = new $model();
```

And this is my source code database connect:

```
$db['default'] = array(
'DSN' => '',
'hostname' => 'xxx',
'username' => 'xxx',
'password' => 'xxx',
'database' => 'xxx',
'dbdriver' => 'sqlsrv',
'dbprefix' => '',
'pconnect' => false,
'db_debug' => false,
'cache_on' => false,
'cachedir' => '',
'char_set' => 'utf8',
'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
'swap_pre' => '',
'encrypt' => false,
'compress' => false,
'stricton' => false,
'failover' => array(),
'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

What should I do?

Comment: what version of `sqlsrv` are you using? as well as php and CI version?

Comment: @vickel CI 3 and sqlsrv current version